# Rule does not trigger even having the facts in WM

Tags: clips

As the title suggests, I have a "generate-hotels" rule which, although being in the correct module and having all the facts that are needed in WM, this rule does not occur.

```
(defrule HOTELS::generate-hotels
  (hotel (name ?name) (tr ?tr) (stars ?s) (price-per-night ?ppn))
  (tourism-resort (name ?tr) (region ?r) (type $? ?t $?) (score ?s))
  (tourism-type ?t)
  (attribute (name best-region) (value ?r) (certainty ?certainty-1))
  (attribute (name best-city) (value ?city&:(eq ?city (sym-cat (str-cat ?r "-") ?tr))) (certainty ?certainty-2))
  (attribute (name best-tourism-type) (value ?t) (certainty ?certainty-3))
  =>
  (assert (attribute (name hotel) (value ?name)
                     (certainty (min ?certainty-1 ?certainty-2 ?certainty-3)))))
```

[image]

Comment: What I expect is that the fact related to hotel2 also appears in WM...

Comment: Rather than attaching pictures of your code, you should post the text of the code instead.

Comment: ok i added it...

Comment: ptoblem solved.. the name of the variable associated with the field stars was equal to the variable associated with the field score... My bad.